# Directshow Application crash after exiting of main()

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I am writing directshow application. Below is the code that works fine but crashes with the error message "App.exe has stopped working". The entire code is written below. Please note that I am using Windows SDK 7.0 which does not have `atlbase.h` and hence I cannot use `CComPtr<IBaseFilter> myFilter;` type of pointer declaration which is supposed to clear memory at exit.

**EDIT:** The application crashes only if I connect all filters explicitly. In this case, the destructor of my filter is not called. If I just connect source filter to renderer (which will internally connect my filter and a demux filter), the destructor of my filter is called and there is no crash. I have put the macro `MANUAL_CONNECT` over the code which causes the crash. I have removed `RemoveFilter` call and replaced it with `Release` call.

I am writing the application code here:

```
void main(WORD32 argc, CHAR *argv[])
{
        // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return;
    }
    {
        IGraphBuilder           *pGraph = NULL;
        IFileSourceFilter       *pFileSourceFilter = NULL;
        IMediaControl           *pControl = NULL;
        IMediaEvent             *pEvent = NULL;
        IBaseFilter             *pSource = NULL;
        IBaseFilter             *pVideoDecode = NULL;
        IBaseFilter             *pVideoRenderer = NULL;
        IEnumPins               *pEnumPins = NULL;
        IPin                    *pPinIn = NULL;
        IPin                    *pPinOut = NULL;
        ULONG                   fetched;
        PIN_INFO                PinInfo;    
        IEnumFilters            *pEnum = NULL;
        BOOL                    stop = FALSE;
        int i;

        // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);

        // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AsyncReader, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pSource);

        hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pSource, NULL);

        hr = pSource->QueryInterface(IID_IFileSourceFilter, (void**)&pFileSourceFilter);

        hr = pFileSourceFilter->Load(L"input.mp4", NULL);

        // Create Ittiam HEVC Decoder instance
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ivdec, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pVideoDecode);

        // Create Video Renderer instance. We have used default video renderer
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_VideoRendererDefault, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&pVideoRenderer);

        // Add decoder filter to the filter graph
        hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pVideoDecode, NULL);

        // Add renderer filter to the filter graph
        hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pVideoRenderer, NULL);

        /**************************************************************/
        /* -- Connecting source filter to demux filter starts here -- */
        /**************************************************************/
        // Enumerate pins of the source filter
        hr = pSource->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
        hr = pEnumPins->Reset();
        // Get pin of source filter. Source filter has only output pin, so no check required
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinOut, &fetched);
        hr = pEnumPins->Release();
#if MANUAL_CONNECT
        // Enumerate pins of the decoder filter
        hr = pVideoDecode->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
        hr = pEnumPins->Reset();
        // Get pin of decoder filter. Decoder filter has 2 pins, so ensure the selected pin is input pin.
        // If not, get another pin
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinIn, &fetched);
        hr = pPinIn->QueryPinInfo(&PinInfo);
        if(PINDIR_OUTPUT == PinInfo.dir)
        {
            hr = pPinIn->Release();
            hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinIn, &fetched);
        }

        // Connect output pin of demux filter to input pin of decoder filter
        hr = pGraph->Connect(pPinOut, pPinIn);

        /*************************************************************/
        /* -- Connecting demux filter to decoder filter ends here -- */
        /*************************************************************/

        /******************************************************************/
        /* -- Connecting decoder filter to renderer filter starts here -- */
        /******************************************************************/
        // Enumerate pins of the decoder filter
        hr = pVideoDecode->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
        hr = pEnumPins->Reset();
        // Get pin of decoder filter. Decoder filter has 2 pins, so ensure the selected pin is output pin.
        // If not, get another pin
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinOut, &fetched);
        hr = pPinOut->QueryPinInfo(&PinInfo);
        if(PINDIR_INPUT == PinInfo.dir)
        {
            hr = pPinOut->Release();
            hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinOut, &fetched);
        }
        hr = pEnumPins->Release();
#endif

        // Enumerate pins of the renderer filter
        hr = pVideoRenderer->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
        hr = pEnumPins->Reset();
        // Get pin of renderer filter. Renderer filter has only input pin, so no check required
        hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinIn, &fetched);
        hr = pPinIn->QueryPinInfo(&PinInfo);

        // Connect output pin of decoder filter to input pin of renderer filter
        hr = pGraph->Connect(pPinOut, pPinIn);

        /****************************************************************/
        /* -- Connecting decoder filter to renderer filter ends here -- */
        /****************************************************************/

        hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
        hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);

            // Note: Do not use INFINITE in a real application, because it
            // can block indefinitely.
        }

        hr = pControl->Stop();

        hr = pSource->Release();
        hr = pVideoDecode->Release();
        hr = pControl->Release();
        hr = pEvent->Release();
        hr = pGraph->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    printf("Exiting main!!\n");
}
```

I have removed error checks from the post but I have all error checks in my code. I can see the `Exiting main!!` print but than the application crashes. Any suggestions on how to debug this? Please let me know if any information is missing. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express for my development.

Comment: You are only checking for errors in like *two* places. It does no good to save the HRESULT value returned from the function if you aren't going to bother to see if it indicates success or failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must terminate all COM activity (specifically: release all COM interface pointers) on the thread before calling `CoUninitialize`, you don't do it.

See, for example, [this code](https://github.com/leixiaohua1020/simplest_directshow_example/blob/master/simplest_directshow_player_custom/simplest_directshow_player_custom.cpp) and its `Release` calls at the `_tmain` bottom.

It makes sense to use more recent version of Visual Studio (2013, 2015), where free community edition already includes ATL and you can enjoy automatic COM interface reference management using `CComPtr` and friends. This is the first advise to those who uses raw COM interface pointers and experience issues managing them incorrectly.

See also:

- [Not releasing filter com object causing a crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136445/not-releasing-filter-com-object-causing-a-crash)
- [Unreleased DirectShow CSource filter makes program crash at process shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295434/unreleased-directshow-csource-filter-makes-program-crash-at-process-shutdown/12364905#12364905)
- [Why does CoUninitialize cause an error on exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653797/why-does-couninitialize-cause-an-error-on-exit)

**UPDATE**: Using raw pointers inaccurately, you keep having leaks:

```
    hr = pGraph->Connect(pPinOut, pPinIn);
    // ...
    hr = pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPinOut, &fetched);
```

`IEnumPin::Next` call overwrites `pPinOut` pointer and leaks a reference.

Comment: When I simply call `hr = pGraph->RenderFile(L"input.mp4", NULL);`, there is no crash. I noticed that my filter's destructor is not being called when I add the filters manually. Any suggestion what might be going wrong? My filter's destructor is being called when directly calling RenderFile.

Comment: Problem found but not sure of the solution. When I manually connect input pin of my filter to file source and output pin to renderer, there is a crash when releasing my filter. If I connect file source to renderer directly (which will internally connect my filter), there is no crash and there is clean exit. How can I manually connect the pins and still ensure clean exit?

Comment: It would be good idea to update source code in the question to reflect your progress in COM interface management. You have not yet fixed the original problem.

Comment: I have edited the original question with current progress.

Comment: @Saurabh there is also a leaked `IBaseFilter` after `pPinIn->QueryPinInfo(&PinInfo)`. And you don't release `pVideoRenderer`, `pFileSourceFilter`, ...

Comment: Thanks [Wimmel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/33499/wimmel), that completes the answer.